# Как вернуть облако меток, чтобы оно опять располагалось справа?

Tags: поддержка, метки, поиск

При отображении новых вопросов я просматриваю только те, которые относятся к отобранным мною меткам (`intags:mine` в поисковом запросе).

После недавнего изменения дизайна облако меток переместилось наверх:

[image: облако меток]

Как вернуть его назад, чтобы оно располагалось справа от списка вопросов?

Comment: Убедить общественность на [meta.se], что так не надо, а надо как раньше. Но это вряд ли случится.

Comment: Лучше бы они [перевод параметров в результатах поиска](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291549/339911) одобрили.

Comment: И если уж останется сверху в одну строку, то надо [разделители добавить](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303545/339911).

Answer (score 3):

## Никак не вернуть!*

---

Как следует из сообщения на MSE: [Testing Search Feature - 'Did you mean'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/303298/339911) происходит глобальная перестройка механизма поиска, затрагивающая в том числе и элементы графического интерфейса, дизайна страницы, короче говоря:

> We have a few different ideas to work on including improving relevancy, indexing by question (so you only see one result for each question page), updating design and more.

<sup>*</sup> Если что-то кажется неправильным или однозначно ошибочным, самый разумный подход, это писать <s>жалобу</s> баг-репорт, фича-реквест на MSE и надеяться, что его примут к сведению.

Может быть проблему получится решить какими-то юзерскриптами, как это делается особо недовольными участниками для некоторых других элементов дизайна.

Comment: Звёздочка у "Никак!" портит весь эффект. Сами-знаете-кто [говорил](https://www.artlebedev.ru/kovodstvo/sections/96/) ещё пятнадцать лет назад.

Comment: @AK [звездочка - это хорошо!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aWsY.png)

Comment: @AK а вообще, `*` внушает надежду!